# How to fetch all email headers without getting the entire message

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

Is there a way to fetch only all of the headers for an email in Mailkit? In AE mail there was a headersonly flag that would call the imap BODY.PEEK[HEADER] query, but in Mailkit it seems you can only fetch headers by specifying what headers you want, using

```
Fetch (IList<UniqueId> uids, MessageSummaryItems items, HashSet<HeaderId> fields, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken)).
```

I tried using this fetch and all of the enums in HeaderId, but there were still quite a few headers that weren't being captured.

I also noticed that GetBodyPart has a headersonly flag, but it requires a bodypart as an input.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast the folder to an `ImapFolder`, you can call:

```
var entity = ((ImapFolder) folder).GetBodyPart (uid, string.Empty, true);
var headers = entity.Headers;
```

There's also a Fetch method that takes a HashSet<string> as well, so you aren't limited to just what is available in HeaderId

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, when you call GetBodyPart with the empty string it won't return all of the headers. It will only return headers that start with "Content-" due to

    'if (partSpecifier.Length == 0) {
    for (int i = entity.Headers.Count; i > 0; i--) {
     var header = entity.Headers[i - 1];

     if (!header.Field.StartsWith ("Content-", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      entity.Headers.RemoveAt (i - 1);
    }
   }'
in the imapfolder GetBodyPart method.

Comment: Before I go and add a `GetMessage(bool headersOnly)`, why do you only want the headers? What are you doing with them?

Comment: I'm converting an automated email test suite directly from AE mail to Mailkit because of the added functionality Mailkit has. However many of our tests rely on the AE's headersonly flag because of performance reasons, and I would like to make as direct a conversion as possible.

Comment: I've just added a bunch of GetHeaders() methods to IMailFolder in [GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/commit/b14be2dbeffd16cedc85ebd35d5125e01e73cea8), but i have not tested that they work yet. Feel free to grab the source and test it out for me :-)

Comment: BTW, not sure if I'll keep the `GetHeaders()` API or stick with the `GetBodyPart(bool headersOnly)` API and add `GetMessage(bool headersOnly)` instead. There's advantages and disadvantages to both...

Comment: Will do! I really appreciate the work you are doing.

Comment: No prob... btw, I've added unit tests now and all seems to work properly. I think I'll end up keeping the GetHeaders() API and [Obsolete]'ing the older GetBodyPart(bool headersOnly) API (feels like a waste of memory to get back a MimeEntity when all you want is the headers).

Comment: MailKit 1.14 has been released with the new `GetHeaders()` feature.